# PhpStorm error with docker volumes: "VirtualBox shared folders should be configured in the Docker cloud settings"

Tags: docker, phpstorm, docker-for-windows, phpstorm-2016.3

This is an issue with PhpStorm 2016.3.3 on Windows. I encountered the following error trying to configure a Docker container:

[image: Example of "VirtualBox shared folders should be configured in the Docker cloud settings"]

I can make the *immediate* error-message go away by going into the `Build, Execution, Deployment > Docker` and add the same folder to the "VirtualBox shared folders" selection...

[image]

... and that unblocks the file-picker ...

[image: Example of unhelpful workaround with file-picker]

...But unfortunately this still does **not** mount when I run the container.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can completely ignore the error by avoiding the file-picker dialog! You don't need to add *any* folders to the "Virtualbox shared folders" section either.

Instead, just manually enter (or copy-paste) a path that uses forward slashes only. So instead of `C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents\some-app`, enter `/c/Users/JohnDoe/Documents/some-app`.

[image: Workaround screenshot]